# How to get the list of all the JS APIs supported by the current browser?

Tags: javascript, browser

I know I can use a website like https://caniuse.com/ciu/comparison to find the specific JS APIs available for specific versions of browsers, but is there a way I can do this using JavaScript?

For example, something like (pseudocode):

```
for functions as function in JS_APIs 
    found.push(function.name)
```

Can this be done or do I have to iteratively do something like the following for every possible JS API name?

```
typeof specific_JS_API_name === "function"
```

Thank you.

Comment: How about putting the names in an array, then loop over the array and test each one for being a function?

Comment: Thanks. Ideally I could magically get the list of names and check them as there are a lot of JS APIs and I'm worried I will miss some or end up with a huge hard coded array.

Comment: Why not just check the ones you're using? "Give me all JS functions ever" seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that a bit more context might help motivate.

Comment: My use case requires I check them all. It's related to bot detection.